# Silverlight RIA Services auth active-directory

Tags: silverlight, active-directory, service, ria

Hi i am new to ria Services 
and i am trying to change the logon from SQL to active-directory and stil using the login form i am using the Silverlight Business Application template as base i have setup ADmembership provider in the website but how do i get Silverlight to use it??

Answer (score 3):

This blog post has the answer. [Silverlight with WCF Ria Services and Active Directory Roles](http://www.dansoltesz.com/post/2010/01/26/WCF-Ria-Services-Active-Directory-Roles.aspx). Thanks Dan for this post!

I am using Silverlight 4 so a few things have changed since this post. I also used the Business Application template for this project.

Step 1. This was already set in the BussinessApplication template in the App.xaml.cs code behind. You do need to comment the line with `webContext.Authentication = new FormsAuthentication();` and uncomment the line `webContext.Authentication = new WindowsAuthentication();`.

Step 2. No change. Add `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` to the web.config under the /configuration/system.web element.

Step 3. RiaContex is now WebContext, so change this in the sample. The first line that loads the user, `RiaContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser(this.Application_UserLoaded, null);` was already in the code.

Step 4. No change. add `<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>` to the web.config under the /configuration/system.web element.

With these small changes the Silverlight Application was connecting to the Active Directory and populated the `WebContext.Current.User.Roles` that I was looking for.